# low performance of send and receiving single message in RTE_RING of DPDK

Tags: dpdk

Hell Stack-Overflow experts.

I am wondering whether there is a good explanation for high latency caused by rte_ring when testing the round-trip latency using 1 burst in (tx rx queue).

I have tested the performance using two nodes (client and server) 
and calculated the elapsed latency of the round-trip of single pingpong. 
The latency is calculated on two different test-cases 
1. elapsed latency of send and receive directly from rx tx queue. 
2. elapsed latency of send and receive from rte_ring.

Here is the result of the latency of RTE_RING generated when I test DPDK on 1 burst (tx rx)

[image]

DPDK+RING is the elapsed latency of using RING to send pingpong messages

DPDK is the elapsed latency of directly sending messages to tx rx queue.

RING is the assumed latency of subtracting DPDK+RING from DPDK latency.

Latency with direct tx rx queue with 1 burst
When I send a single messages (512, 1024, 4096 bytes) (1 burst for each request) and receive 1 burst of response from the remote server. 
the latency is approximately 4 ~ 8 microseconds.

RTE_RING Latency with 1 burst 
When I use rte_ring to send and receive data from client and server, the latency increases like crazy which is 59 microseconds to 100 microseconds.

RTE_RING Latency with 10 bursts 
When I use bursts for example (10 messages per request)
and calculate the elapsed latency by dividing the total elapsed time with the total ping-pong messages (total-latency)/(total ping-pong received messages).
I could get a very good performance using rte_ring 7 ~ 10 microseconds.

I was wondering whether someone can tell me what I should look at in order to decrease the latency of RTE_RING. 
Because even though I don't use multiple bursts, the latency should be low.

Here are the codes of client-side that are used to add the packets in the tx-ring

```
    if (rte_ring_enqueue(tx_ring, client_txt) < 0) {
        printf("[user] Failed to send message - message discarded\n");
    } else {
        total_sent++;
        if (chara_debug) printf("[%d] Client txt data::[%.24s...]__length::[%ld]\n", total_sent++, client_txt, strlen(client_txt));
    }
```

here are the codes for sending the data to tx-queue

```
void
l2fwd_tx_loop()
{
    struct rte_mbuf *pkts_burst[MAX_PKT_BURST];
    struct rte_mbuf *m;

    unsigned lcore_id;
    unsigned portid, nb_rx;
    struct lcore_queue_conf *qconf;
    struct rte_eth_dev_tx_buffer *buffer;

    lcore_id = 1;
    qconf = &lcore_queue_conf[lcore_id];

    struct rte_mbuf *rm[10];
    portid = qconf->rx_port_list[0];
    char* data;
    char* send_msg;
    struct message obj;
    struct fuse_message * e = NULL;
    char *msg, *_msg;
    void *__msg;
    int total_tx;


    while (!force_quit) {

        total_tx=0;
        while(total_tx<batch){
                if (rte_ring_dequeue(tx_ring, &__msg) < 0) {
                    usleep(5);
                    // sched_yield();

                    // printf("Failed to recv message - message discarded\n");
                } else {
                    _msg = (char *)__msg;
                    rm[total_tx] = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(test_pktmbuf_pool);
                    data = rte_pktmbuf_append(rm[total_tx], PKT_SIZE*sizeof(char));


                    if(strcmp(hostname,"c3n24")==0) {
                        data += sizeof(struct ether_hdr) - 2; // ASU SERVER
                        l2fwd_mac_updating(rm[total_tx], portid); // ASU SERVER
                    }

                    rte_memcpy(data, _msg, PKT_SIZE*sizeof(char));

                     if(PKT_SIZE==1024) printf("[%d]\n",total_tx);

                    if(chara_debug) printf("[%d] send msg in DPDK: %s",total_tx, _msg);
                    total_tx++;
                    // rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, rm[0], 60);
                }
        }


        int rtn = rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, 0, rm, total_tx);
        for(int i=0; i<total_tx; i++) {
            rte_pktmbuf_free(rm[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

here are the codes for receiving from the rx queue

```
void
l2fwd_rx_loop() {
    struct rte_mbuf *pkts_burst[MAX_PKT_BURST];
    struct rte_mbuf *m;

    unsigned lcore_id;
    unsigned i, j, portid, nb_rx;
    struct lcore_queue_conf *qconf;
    struct rte_eth_dev_tx_buffer *buffer;

    lcore_id = rte_lcore_id();
    qconf = &lcore_queue_conf[lcore_id];

    struct rte_mbuf *rm[1];

    while (!force_quit) {
        /*
         * Read packet from RX queues
         */
            portid = qconf->rx_port_list[0];
            nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst((uint8_t) portid, 0, pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST);

            for (j = 0; j < nb_rx; j++) {
                m = pkts_burst[j];
                int rte_mbuf_packet_length = rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(m);
                if (rte_mbuf_packet_length == (PKT_SIZE)) {
                    // rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, 60);
                    if(strcmp(hostname,"c3n24")==0) {
                        // dpdk_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, PKT_SIZE, sizeof(struct ether_hdr)-2);
                        dpdk_packet_process(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void * ), PKT_SIZE, sizeof(struct ether_hdr) - 2);
                    }
                }
                rte_pktmbuf_free(m);
            }
    }

}
```

here is the code for receiving the data from rx-ring

```
    while (batched_packets<targ->batch) {
        if (rte_ring_dequeue(rx_ring, &_msg) < 0){
            usleep(5);
            // sched_yield();

        }
        else {
            recv_msg = (char *) _msg;
            if (chara_debug) printf("[%d] Server reply data::[%.24s...]__length::[%ld]\n", batched_packets, recv_msg, strlen(recv_msg));
            total_recved++;
            batched_packets++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your advice, Andriy Berestovskyy
(If you can finalize your professional advice based on my findings, then I will mark that as the suitable answer.)

I have found the answer, The design of the threads caused the latency problem.

rte_ring should be busy polling all the time.

The thread that was calculating the latency was sending the packets with rte_ring tx but also receiving the packets from the rte_ring rx. This was the main cause of the latency.

So when I implement dpdk, I need to make sure that rte_rings are not interrupted and do the busy polling all the time. So If I use rte_ring tx and rte_ring rx then I need to use two threads that does the tx and rx separately.

Probably Andriy would have noticed the problem if I have shown all the source codes, 
but I tried to simplify the source-codes as much as possible so I can get response from more advisors.

Never expected the design of the threads could cause this much latency.

Comment: Good to know you have it resolved. It is still not clear, how do you explain why DPDK+RING+SLEEP is 64us but DPDK+RING+YIELD is 19860us? What exactly caused such a difference?

Comment: All I could tell you is I did exactly what you told me, swap the sleep with other dpdk apis and those produced the worst result. Since the DPDK sample applications use usleep(5) while busy looping the rte_ring, I assumed that is the right approach. indeed if you don't add usleep(5) in the rte_ring, your performance degrades.  However, none of this matters, if I only assign  on thread per rx-ring or tx-ring, I am not used to multi-threading or thread programming, so maybe it was an obvious thing.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Fix the bug in the code:

This loop might cause all kinds of troubles:

```
    int rtn = rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, 0, rm, total_tx);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_tx; i++) {
        rte_pktmbuf_free(rm[i]);
    }
```

The `rte_eth_tx_burst()` frees the buffers, so we do not need to free them. We need to free (or retry to send) only the difference between buffers we have passed to the `rte_eth_tx_burst()` (in this case it is `total_tx`) and number of buffers actually sent/enqueued by the `rte_eth_tx_burst()`.

So the code should look like:

```
    int rtn = rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, 0, rm, total_tx);
    for (int i = rtn; i < total_tx; i++) { // Loop from rtn, not from 0
        rte_pktmbuf_free(rm[i]);
    }
```

## 2. Looks like `usleep()`'s are too long for you

Please note that the argument we pass to `usleep()` is the *minimum* time interval.

Remove them completely to confirm. If that is the cause, change the `usleep()`s to either:

- `rte_pause()` -- the shortest pause possible on a given CPU
- `rte_delay_ms()` / `rte_delay_us()` -- basically repeats `rte_pause()`'s for a given time interval.
- `sched_yield()` -- yields CPU to another thread (if any). Basically the shortest `usleep()`

Also make sure all the `printf()`'s are either commented out or compiled out from the code, because each `printf()` call introduces a tremendous delay as well...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, However, if I switch the usleep(5) to rte_pause or rte_delay_us() or exclude the usleep() completely, I get a massive high latency (23981.773438 us) instead of improving the performance. I don't understand because I only have one thread for producer and one thread for consumer.

Comment: @SunghoHong what about `sched_yield()`?

Comment: `sched_yield()` produce 19860.160156 us while `usleep(5)` produce 64.052063 us. I was thinking could it be possible that I am not dequeueing the packets in the rte_ring by bursts?. because the performance is good when I simply increase the number of single burst to 10 in tx,rx queue, and when I use 1 burst in tx rx queue this happens.. So I was thinking maybe rte_ring is taking more time to find the packets when the tx rx queue bursts is 1 ?

Comment: I have added some code that how I implemented the rx-ring rx-queue, tx-ring and tx-queue

Comment: It is not quite clear who does enqueue in `rx_ring`. But there is a bug in the code: after `rte_eth_tx_burst()` we need to free only the difference between `rtn` and `total_tx`, not all the buffers. Please see DPDK examples.

Comment: the total_tx exactly does what you are saying. It is the total tx that you have sent for one request.

Comment: hmm. I think one possibility is that rx_ring is enqueued by logical core 1 and it is dequeued by logical core 4. Since it is passing messages between two threads, is it possible that this cause the latency?

Comment: Please fix the bug first. See my updated answer above for the details. Also please show how you enqueue into the `rx_ring`. At the moment it is showed as `dpdk_packet_process()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the problem of latency was not in  using the DPDK API, it was the design of the DPDK threads that caused the latency.